# Disable/remove MacDrive from within MacOS X

Tags: windows, macos, boot, bsod, windows-8-preview

I've just tried upgrading Windows 7 to Windows 8 CP on my macbook air and after it restarted, I've repaired my MacDrive installation which claimed that it had problems.

Since that I keep getting BSoDs on boot and I can't even boot in the recovery environment or in safe mode. Is there any way I can make it from within Lion so that Windows won't try to load MacDrive's disk driver? (I have writing access to my windows partition, so editing files won't be a problem)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the `macdrive.sys` file on your Windows partition (probably in system32), and try moving it/renaming it. That should (ham-fistedly, but effectively) remove the driver from Windows' load order.

Try searching different case combinations, like `Macdrive.sys` or `MacDrive.sys` if you can't find it, since OSX is a case-sensitive OS.

Comment: I've removed MDFSYSNT.SYS and MDPMGRNT.SYS (the two MacDrive-related drivers) and I still get the same INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE blue screen...

Comment: Then I'm not sure this is MacDrive related. Try running the startup repair tools off of the windows 7 installer disk.